# How to insert space by punctuation?

Tags: python, regex

I have strings like so: `hey what is up!`, `"what did you say?"`, `"he said 'well'"`, etc. and a regex expression like so: `[!%&'\(\)$#\"\/\\*+,-.:;<=>?@\[\]^_´`{|}~]´. These are my delimiters and into the strings shown a space shall be inserted like so: `"hey what is up !"`, `"what did you say ?"`, `"he said ' well '"`. So if one of the delimiters is in front of another character sequence, add a space, and if its is after, add space as well.

How can I achieve this? I do not want to split by these delimiters.

Here's my solution but I would be curious how to solve it with regex.

```
    space = set("[!%&'()$#\"/\*+,-.:;<=>?@[]^_´`{|}~]")
    for sent in self.sentences:
        sent = list(sent)
        for i, char in enumerate(sent):
            # Make sure to respect length of string when indexing
            if i != 0:
                # insert space in front if char is punctuation
                if sent[i] in space and sent[i - 1] != " ":
                    sent.insert(i, " ")
            if i != len(sent)-1:
                # insert space after if char is punctuation
                if sent[i] in space and sent[i + 1] != " ":
                    sent.insert(i + 1, " ")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could expand your pattern to catch optional spaces and then replace by capture group plus spaces before and after (loop only for demo, not neccessary):

```python
import re


strings = ["hey what is up!", "what did you say?", "he said 'well'"]

pattern = r'(\s?[!%&\'\(\)$#\"\/\\*+,-.:;<=>?@\[\]^_´{|}~]\s?)'
for string in strings:
    print(re.sub(pattern, r' \1 ', string))
```

This will give this output:

```
hey what is up !
what did you say ?
he said  ' well '
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a loop that goes through your strings and when it finds a ponctuation character use the slice function to cut your string in half and concatenate with a space in between.
For example:

```
for i in yourString:
  if yourString[i] == '!':
    newString = yourString.slice(0, i) + " " + yourString.slice(i + 1)
```

It only checks for "!" but you could replace it with a dictionnary of ponctuation characters

Comment: I don't think that's going to work

Comment: The code might not be optimal because I did it fast but I did this way to format phone numbers and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Without the aid of the *re* module you could simply do this:

```
punctuation = "!%&'()$#\"/\\*+,-.:;<=>?@[]^_´{|}~"
mystring = "Well hello! How are you?"
mylist = list(mystring)
i = 0
for c in mystring:
  if c in punctuation:
    mylist.insert(i, ' ')
    i += 2
  else:
    i += 1
print(''.join(mylist))
```